# Нужно ли оборачивать тело письма в теги

Tags: стандарт, php, email, отправка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли оборачивать тело письма в теги <html> <body> ?
Где посмотреть стандарт, которому нужно придерживаться?

```
$mail = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" ></head><body>Text</body></html>;
// or
$mail = 'Text';
```

Comment: по стандарту надо, но в большинстве web based почтовых сервисов это не работает. так-что не надо.

Comment: Тут назревает еще попутный вопрос... Если нужно писать теги <html>, <body> то нужно ли указывать, что это html5? а если нужно указывать, то по w3c нужно указывать и title, meta в <head>... Короче я в растерянности. 
P.s. В данный момент приходит письмо нормально со структурой как я показал в вопросе. Просто не понятно как обрабатывают эти письма web based сервисы.
Или вы просто имеете в виду, что эти теги просто игнорируются в  web based сервисах и используется только body?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, только если этот HTML действительно зачем-то нужен, скажем сделать ссылку в виде картинки.

Смотрите пример.
<?php
$admin_mail = "ящик";

$message = "IP адрес: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

mail($admin_mail, 'Заказ', $message);
?>

Comment: оп имел ввиду в случае, если письмо в html, нужно  ли оборачивать его в теги <html>...

Comment: Да ,письмо именно html.